# Numeric class and method missing

Tags: ruby, numeric, self

I am a newbie in Ruby and I can't figure out why when I run this ruby script,

```
class Numeric
 def method_missing(arg)
    puts self
  end
end

puts 5
```

it returns

```
[...]
5
```

I thought the self should only return `[...]`, since no arguments gets passed in.

Thanks!

Comment: BTW, why did you *"thought the self should only return `[...]`"*? I was quite surprised at first.

Comment: I thought `[...]` meant array in ruby. So I thought it should return a empty array.

Comment: Interesting question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`puts` handles arrays in a special way. Therefore, `puts 5` attempts to call `5.to_ary` and when implementing `method_missing`, it calls it with an argument of `:to_ary`.

Within `method_missing` you call `puts self` which is equivalent to `puts 5`. This is a recursion which Ruby shows as `[...]`.

This recursive array produces the same output:

```
ary = []
#=> []
ary << ary
#=> [[...]]
```

Comment: So the `5` in `puts 5` is seen as an array in ruby?

Comment: Yes, because `5` responds to `to_ary` (via `method_missing`)

Comment: `[...]` What does this mean? My guess is that this is a recursion calling itself over and over again. So that's  a lot of `5`?

Comment: @BillCheng it's an recursive array, I've updated my answer with another example.

Comment: To be more precise, the inner `puts self` detects an attempt to output a recursive array and outputs `[...]` instead (returning `nil`) whereas the outer `puts 5` just outputs `5`, because `to_ary` returned `nil`.

Comment: Just curious, why doesn't ruby just throw a `stack level too deep` error?

Comment: Because it's Ruby ;-)